# Cassandra does not start as a service

Tags: cassandra

If I try to run cassandra as a service:

```
sudo service cassandra start
```

no errors or logs get traced to terminal, seems that it's working..
if I try to run on another node:

```
/usr/bin/nodetool status mynamespace
```

I get its status as DN, Only when run cassandra like this:

```
/usr/sbin/cassandra -f
```

then `/usr/bin/nodetool status mynamespace` would state the node as UN:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: are you using datastax ?how did you install cassandra ?

Comment: I've installed it via ansible, here `- action: apt pkg="{{item}}" state=installed force=yes
  with_items:
    - dsc30
    - cassandra-tools`

Comment: How would I know if its using datastax or regular Cassandra?

Comment: what does  `sudo service cassandra status` says?

Comment: It seems you are using datastax community edition - dsc30

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? i ran into the same thing and can't seem to figure this out

Answer (score 3):

Can you check the `/var/log/cassandra/system.log` after the service start? If you ran with `cassandra -f` first you may of created files with your user instead of the `cassandra` user which would cause permission issues when service starts

Answer (score 2):

To start cassandra as a service, I wrote a service for cassandra at `/etc/systemd/system/cassandra.service`. Have a look-

```
[Unit]
Description=Cassandra Cluster Node Daemon

[Service]
Type=forking
User=cassandra
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/echo "Starting Cassandra Daemon"
ExecStart=/opt/apache-cassandra-2.2.4/bin/cassandra
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/echo "Cassandra Daemon Running"

ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/rm -rf /data/cassandra/saved_caches;/usr/bin/echo "Cassandra Daemon Stopped"

SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Then-

`# systemctl start cassandra`

Here, `ExecStart=<cassandra-path>` and `/data/cassandra/saved_caches`-is your `saved_caches` path.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if your service is running?

`sudo service cassandra restart`

[image: check if cassandra has exited]

if it says exited in green then it's not even running, so you just need to restart your service

`sudo service cassandra status`